# The EF many-to-many relationship migration doesnt seem to generate the correct migration-plan

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I've got two classes that both reference eachother in an Entity Framework code-first approach.

```
public class Owner : IAuditBase
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ShortCode { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdatedDate { get; set; }
    public List<CertificateType> CertificateTypes { get; set; }

    public List<User> OwnerUsers { get; set; }

}

public class User
{
    [Key]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string ChipId { get; set; }
    public string Alias { get; set; }
    public Guid ResetCodeId { get; set; }
    public string ResetCode { get; set; }
    public Owner CurrentOwner { get; set; }

    public List<Owner> UserOwners { get; set; }
}
```

After adding the two lists (OwnerUsers and UserOwners), i would expect entity framework to add a new table, connecting the ID's of Owner and User, that is not the case.

```
public partial class addownerstousers : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        AddColumn("dbo.Owners", "User_Email", c => c.String(maxLength: 128));
        AddColumn("dbo.Users", "Owner_Id", c => c.Int());
        CreateIndex("dbo.Owners", "User_Email");
        CreateIndex("dbo.Users", "Owner_Id");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.Owners", "User_Email", "dbo.Users", "Email");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.Users", "Owner_Id", "dbo.Owners", "Id");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.Users", "Owner_Id", "dbo.Owners");
        DropForeignKey("dbo.Owners", "User_Email", "dbo.Users");
        DropIndex("dbo.Users", new[] { "Owner_Id" });
        DropIndex("dbo.Owners", new[] { "User_Email" });
        DropColumn("dbo.Users", "Owner_Id");
        DropColumn("dbo.Owners", "User_Email");
    }
}
```

It adds only one foreignkey to each table, pretty much creating a two-way one-to-many relationship. I have seen the migrator working this out before, so i just cant wrap my head around why this happens now. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Try to add fluent mapping (`HasMany-WithMany`).

Comment: That works! Thanks! Though it feels a bit hacky, ive seen this working without having to define that kind of stuff before? Also feel free to add your comment as an answer

Answer (score 0):

What version of EF are you using?   For navigation properties (properties that refer to other objects - just like you have), you should make them "virtual" (depending on version of EF of course).

For further info, see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj713564(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: Running EF 6.1.3, virtual doesnt make any difference